# lighttpd mod_flv_streaming with Flex 4 OSMF VideoPlayer component

Tags: apache-flex, lighttpd, osmf

I try to get the OSMF working with lighttpd FLV streaming.

The mod_flv_streaming works through appending a start=keyframe parameter to the FLV URL. The client has to search the nearest keyframe when the user hits the scrub bar to jump to a different position of the video.

Usually, one would create a new NetStream for each "jump" with the appropriate keyframe information and seek to correct position. However, I have some trouble finding the correct place to put these adjustments into the OSMF.

What I need:

- Event listener if the user changes the play position using the scrub bar (maybe VideoPlayer.scrubBar -> FlexEvent.CHANGE_END)
- Appending the start parameter to the URL and start playing the stream from there

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.